# Twitter Bootstrap Error Using Less

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Following [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics) video

After generating the app, scaffolding, updating gemfile, running bundle install, and running rails server, getting ERROR. 
Am using the gem

> 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

, is there a reason why  it is having an issue with "less?" =>

> ActionView::Template::Error (cannot load such file -- less   (in
>   /Users/ryanmindigo/store/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)):

```
    2: <html>
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Store</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2789023687141131830_70195710799000'
  app/controllers/products_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less file, may not be necessary with updated gem. Please comment if a new error appears so we could see some more.